# best way to handle errors in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I am stuck a bit, I have a little form and auth system - Sentry.

1) Get data from Input and validate it. 
It's okay, I get it, check with rules, set messageBag

```
<?php
     $validation->getMessageBag()->setFormat(Config::get('project/config.errors_delimiters'));
?>
```

Then I return page `withErrors` method. And prints `validation` errors.

2) Next step will be to login users, for example. This mean, that I need to use a Sentry [manual](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry#sentry-authenticate-).

But now I have a problem: how to show errors or store errors.
I have:

- Error messages via validation
- Error messages via Sentry
- Custom Errors
- Success messages
- Info messages

Which the best practice to store this messages? How to send it to a view? And how to parse it in a view? Also how to set delimiters style?

Of course I can create tons of flash, session, and other types of data and then send this into a view, but I think it is ridiculous. I think there is a simple method which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. This is how I handle it.

Because validation errors uses MessageBag, what I did is

```
$messages = new MessageBag;
```

and then if you run into any error, you could do

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $messages->add("error", $e->getMessage());
}
```

and if you have other errors returned you can merge it

```
$messages->merge($other_messages)
```

which includes validation messages $validation->messages().

Because messagebag accepts keys, you can add other type by `$messages->add('info', 'ok')`

And then in your template, or controller, you can get messages of that type by

```
$messages->get('error')
```

after you checked with

```
$messages->has('error')
```

Comment: Yeah, I haven't stopped my researches about this problem. I found it in API documentation. And now I have another problem. Here we have three errors: [Error: "Your password is wrong" -> validation], [Warning: "Login limit" -> my_app], [Info: "I'm a cat" ->my_app]. You know bootstraps divs: <div class = "...">:message</div>, but if I'll merge errors into one bag, I can only display one type of errors. I think to create a helper, which will work like this: gets "error|message", parses this string and outputs correct string with styles. Or maybe I should use flashdata? Anyway, I need go deep.